# Can VLookup work with a dynamic array (determined by strings)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

If I make my Vlookup formula =VLOOKUP(B21,F_CCIII_CPI, 2, FALSE), it returns the result just fine.

If I make my If I make my Vlookup formula =VLOOKUP(B21,"F_" & "CCIII_CPI", 2, FALSE), it doesn't work.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indirect is what you are looking for

```
=VLOOKUP(B21,INDIRECT("F_" & "CCIII_CPI"), 2, FALSE)
```

Basically Indirect takes text that represents a range and makes Excel recognize it as a range.

i.e. `=Indirect("A" & 2)` will refer to `A2`

Answer (score 0):

You can also name the array and then refer to the array by its name.

For example:
You could highlight cells A1:B5 in Sheet1 then right click and "define name" as Array1.

then in Sheet2, define A1:B5 as Array2.

your Vlookup would then be:

```
 =VLOOKUP(B21, Array1, 2, FALSE)
```

to change the reference to sheet2's data you would just change the name to array2

If your reference includes '&' to connect two seperate parts of the reference name, then Indirect would need to be used

Example:

```
=VLOOKUP(B21, INDIRECT("Array" & B20), 2, FALSE)
```

In the above case we can change the array reference by changing the value of cell B20 from 1 to 2 (completing the reference as either Array1 or Array2)

Best,

Comment: Yes I realize this. I was just going into more detail and including some additional reasoning for using Indirect. as i explained above, indirect is best used when another cells value is being used as the modifier in the reference.  Thank you for clarifying 'guitarthrower'

Comment: Gotcha. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Thank You! I'm excited to help out